# Inserting image in submit button

Tags: html, css

There is a simple form in my website

```
<form>
 <input type="textbox" class="Name">
--------------
 <input type="submit" class="Button" value="Update">
</form>
```

I have to insert an image along with the text "Update" in the submit button.(without using  a background-image property)

Comment: Use a `<button>` instead. However, you really shouldn't. The image would be styling, not content, and so should not be in the button...but rather in the CSS.

Comment: Or you could use the new `input[type=image]` - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html

Comment: Using <button> will not run the form as it is not considered as form element

Comment: It will if you hook it up right.

Comment: yeah! it worked thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<button>` like so :

```
<button type="submit"><img src="your/path" />Update</button>
```